# Return Model but it's null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model, imageresizer

I'm using Imageresizer and uploading a photo. I want to get the URL that I receive and return it to my View. I have the URL that I want, but I can't return it further... This is my code at the moment:

```
public ActionResult UploadPhoto(Image img, HttpPostedFileBase file, ProfilePageModel model)
{
    var currentUser = CommunitySystem.CurrentContext.DefaultSecurity.CurrentUser;
    bool isAccepted = false;

    string fileName = string.Empty;
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string fName = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        // Generate each version
        foreach (string fileKey in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Keys)
        {
            HttpPostedFile uploadFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[fileKey];
            // Generate a filename (GUIDs are best).
            fileName = Path.Combine("~/uploads/", fName + format);

            // Let the image builder add the correct extension based on the output file type
            ImageBuilder.Current.Build(uploadFile, fileName, new ResizeSettings(
                "width=300;format=jpg;mode=max;crop=20,20,80,80;cropxunits=100;cropyunits=100"));
            model.fileName = fileName;        
        }
        return RedirectToAction("EditProfile");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("EditProfile");
}
```

When I run this, "uploading a file and press Submit" I get that the model is null, the model contains information about a profile like the name, what country you're from, and so on.

I somehow need to add values to my model so I can return it (so it won't crash). Any ideas?

Comment: You are not showing relevant code. You are redirected to `/EditProfile/`, which action method supposedly returns `View()` without a model. If that is not the case, do you mean you get a `NullReferenceException` at `model.fileName = fileName;`?

Comment: Alright I see!
Problem is that I get value from my model.fileName but as u can see I assign my profilepagemodel and its value in that model is null except the filename.. so it crashes.. im using redirecttoaction("editprofile",model) <- here i send my model further my edit page. where I want the filename values to writeout in a image src,, weird eh

Comment: **Where** does the exception occur and what does it actually look like?

Comment: it occurs when im trying to redirect to editprofile and when i added to also return the model. it says : value cannot be null. and its not the model.filename that's null! its the other stuff thats exist in my profilepagemodel.

Answer (score 2):

For the model to have values, its properties need to exist in the `form`. You'll need to at least add hidden fields for each property you want sent back on a `POST`.

Comment: Problem is, They do exist but in a different method called " save profile" :s

Comment: @user2862542, they have to exist in the `form` you're posting.

Comment: u mean my method? it has to exist in my method called uploadPhoto?

Comment: @user2862542, if the model is getting into this method as `null`, that's because the `form` that `POST`ed to it didn't have the fields in it.

Answer (score 2):

first problem is that from the code, it seems you are NOT returning the model in your RedirectToAction methods, of course depends if you are wanting to do this.

but if the model is null then it means that the items are not being posted back to the controller action.

Comment: hm, I know I dont return any model information atm but Im thinking abt what to return, I cant just return the model.filename, it has the value i want.. but if i return it, everything else in the model will be null. i somehow need to get values to this method for the model xD if u know what I mean.. @ahmed ilyas

Comment: not sure what you mean... if you return it, everything else in the model will be null? no.. if the model has values, then it will return those values in the model. nothing will be null unless you set it to null or the model being posted does not get created in the pipeline to be given to the controller.